# Continuously getting the error HTTP 500

Tags: hibernate, servlets

I wrote a simple web based application insertion program using Hibernate in eclipse IDE but all i got is this error..Can anyone tell me what i need to do??

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception


root cause 

java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Error reading configuration file
    java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:224)
    java.util.ServiceLoader.parse(ServiceLoader.java:301)
    java.util.ServiceLoader.access$200(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:349)
    java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:432)
    org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:247)
    org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:53)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.<init>(BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.<init>(BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java:66)
    org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:76)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1850)
    org.servlet.Insert.doGet(Insert.java:87)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Stay Out!! (The system cannot find the file specified)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
    java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:152)
    java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:89)
    sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
    sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
    sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:98)
    sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:150)
    java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1035)
    java.util.ServiceLoader.parse(ServiceLoader.java:296)
    java.util.ServiceLoader.access$200(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:349)
    java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:432)
    org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:247)
    org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:53)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.<init>(BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.<init>(BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java:66)
    org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:76)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1850)
    org.servlet.Insert.doGet(Insert.java:87)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Error Reading Configuration and FileNotFoundException

Comment: You should add more detail like classpath configuration, web.xml or do you use other web frameworks?

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan I know the error is self explanatory.I'm continuously scratching my head thinking which file is missing.And how do i recover from that error.Anyways thanks for your reply

Comment: The error statement lets you know which file is missing - `D:\Stay Out!!`. Do you have that file?

Comment: I don't understand when i build at the first time no error has occurred and the program ran smoothly,then second time why this is happening.Actually i have eclipse workspace saved in D-drive and all the hibernate jars and jdk installed in C drive.Do i need to shift my workspace from D-drive.

Comment: Try placing the files in the resources folder of the project, it always works for me and solves this unexplained behavior, sometimes works, sometimes does't :D

Comment: Why is this so..as i created my workspace in C drive and ran the program no error has occured..can anyone tell me the reason behind this.And what are the class variable needs to be set??

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't have that file - d:\Stay Out!! - on your (accesible) file system. Anyway, it will help if you follow some guidelines in naming your files, e.g. no whitespaces and fancy characters like "!"